# SQL select MAX data within each 12 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called temp.  In this table I have Date and Value.

```
Date               | Value
2016/04/01 07:00am |   1
2016/04/01 09:00am |   2
2016/04/01 11:00am |   3
...
2016/04/01 07:00pm |   5
2016/04/01 11:00pm |   2
...
2016/04/02 07:00am |   10
2016/04/02 09:00am |   13
2016/04/02 11:00am |   1
...
2016/04/02 07:00pm |   32
2016/04/02 09:00pm |   40
```

I would like to return:

```
Date               | Value
04/01/2016 11:00am | 3
04/01/2016 07:00pm | 5
04/02/2016 09:00am | 13
04/02/2016 09:00pm | 40
```

The idea is to group in 12 hour intervals and then find the max value of said group.

So far I have:

```
SELECT t.date, max(t.value) 
FROM temp t
WHERE t.Date between DATEADD(hour, 7, '04/01/2016') and DATEADD(minute, 1859, '04/02/2016')
GROUP BY DATEPART(Hour, t.date)%12, t.date
ORDER BY Date
```

But it returns all the data, no 12 hour groups.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you 12-hour groups the same every day - midnight-to-noon and 12:01 - 11:59pm?

Comment: yes, same every day.

Comment: If your date actually has the am/pm in it you could additionally group it by last two characters of the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `MAX` as you don't want to group by the date, you want the single instance of the datetime that has the largest value. Therefore you can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION` based on the date and AM/PM period to get the row with the largest value in that period (`ORDER BY t.value DESC`):

```
SELECT date, value
FROM
(SELECT t.date, 
    t.value,
    ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(t.date AS date), CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, t.date) < 12 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
        ORDER BY t.value DESC) AS rownum
    FROM temp t
    WHERE t.Date between DATEADD(hour, 7, '04/01/2016') and DATEADD(minute, 1859, '04/02/2016')
) max_val
WHERE max_val.rownum = 1
ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: That returned all of my data again, no groups.

Comment: Sorry forgot to `CAST` to `date` in the `PARTITION` (assuming a recent version of SQL?)...

Comment: Wait, I need the groups to be between 04/01 7:00am - 04/01 7:00pm, then 04/01 7:00pm - 04/02 07:00am.

Comment: So replace the DATEPART(hour, t.date) < 12 with DATEADD(hour, -7, t.date) <12?

Comment: No actually you will need `DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(hour, -7, t.date)) < 12`

Comment: What if I wanted to only select the date range from 7:00am - 7:00pm, per day?

Comment: Then use `DATEPART` in your `WHERE` clause to limit the records coming back to those with an hour between 7 and 19.

Comment: That works if I only have 1 column of value, what if I have multiple columns?  value1, value2, etc.  I need to have the results in 1 table or else I'd use a while loop...any ideas?